# uitableview scrolling override the textcolor of uilabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting override color of UIlabel which is onmy tableview custom cell. When I m scrolling tableview it's text get override.

[image: Override textcolor "Tower didn't respond"]

Comment: where did you set the color ??

Comment: show some code where you set the color

Comment: are you adding those labels? in your cells?

Comment: can you post the code of your `cellForRow` method?

Comment: man, include your relevant code.. when you go to doctors, you don't just give them your picture and tell them to cure you base on that

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code that colors the labels inside awakeFromNib in cell class not inside cellForRow as the color gradient is being added multiple times to the label because of dequeuing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer 
I have created 2 cells for it
 1. Blinking red 
 2. and second static text color 
 Now data is not overlapped and cell is showing properly with blinking effect.

and it is working fine.

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *strCellId = @"HomeControllerCell";
    HomeControllerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellId];

```
static NSString *strCellBlink = @"HomeControllerCellBlink";
HomeControllerCell *cellBlink = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellBlink];


NSDictionary *dictTemp = [arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

NSString *strDispatchColor = @"";
    if([dictTemp objectForKey:@"DispatchColor"] != nil && ![[dictTemp objectForKey:@"DispatchColor"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
       strDispatchColor = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"DispatchColor"];

```
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strDispatchColor] isEqualToString:KColorRed]) {
        cell.lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strDispatchColor] isEqualToString:KColorGreen]) {
        cell.lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strDispatchColor] isEqualToString:KColorYellow]) {
        cell.lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strDispatchColor] isEqualToString:KColorWhite]) {

        cell.lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.lblStatus.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:38.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:149.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.lblStatus.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.2, 1.2);

    }else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strDispatchColor] isEqualToString:KColorFlashingRed]){
        // Blinking animation

        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue=dispatch_queue_create("textShowing", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // store the downloaded image in your model
       cellBlink.lblStatus.alpha = 1;
       cellBlink.lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
           cellBlink.lblStatus.alpha = 0;
       } completion:nil];
   });
  });
        return cellBlink;
}
```